# Accessing method in component with Provide/Inject in Vue 3 Typescript, Error Object is possibly 'undefined'

Tags: typescript, vue.js

Why can't I call `loginWithRedirect` within header.vue component ​using inject? (Vue 3, Typescript)

> ERROR in src/components/global/HeaderMenu.vue:77:17 TS2339: Property
> 'loginWithRedirect' does not exist on type 'Auth0Plugin'.
> 75 |   methods: {
> 76 |     login() {
>
> > 77 |       this.auth.loginWithRedirect();
> > |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> > 78 |     },
> > 79 |     logout() {
> > 80 |       // this.$AuthPlugin.logout();

I'm new to typescript and have a question regarding the proper use of `inject` (in the context of typescript and Vue 3.) The initial problem was answered [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cF9C.png). From my understanding, I did the following.

Main.js `.provide('authPlugin', AuthPlugin)`

```
​async function init() {
     ​const AuthPlugin = await Auth0.init({
       ​onRedirectCallback: (appState) => {
         ​router.push(appState && appState.targetUrl ? appState.targetUrl : window.location.pathname);
       ​},
       ​clientId: 'xxxx',
       ​domain: 'xxxx',
       ​audience: 'xxxx'
     ​});
     ​const app = createApp(App);
     ​// library.add(faLink, faUser, faPowerOff);
     ​app
       ​.use(AuthPlugin)
       ​// .use(store)
       ​.use(router)
       ​// Make BootstrapVue available throughout project
       ​.use(BootstrapVue3)
   ​
       ​.provide('authPlugin', AuthPlugin)
       ​// .component("font-awesome-icon", FontAwesomeIcon)
       ​.mount('#app');
   ​}
   ​
   ​init();
```

In my `header.vue` component I want to use `loginWithRedirect` from the auth index.ts. To facilitate this I added the following in components/header.vue...

**Imported and set type**

```
   ​import { defineComponent } from 'vue';
   ​import { inject } from 'vue';
   ​import { Auth0 } from '@/auth';
   ​export type TAuthPlugin = typeof Auth0;
```

**​In the `setup()` method of the same header.vue component...**

```
   ​setup() {
       ​const auth = inject<TAuthPlugin>('Auth');
```

This appears to give me access to the method `login` via `this.auth`

[image: console log]

However, if I try to access `this.auth.login` I get an. error, why?

```
src/components/global/HeaderMenu.vue:77:7
TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.
    75 |   methods: {
    76 |     login() {
  > 77 |       this.auth.loginWithRedirect();
       |       ^^^^^^^^^
    78 |     },
    79 |     logout() {
    80 |       // this.$AuthPlugin.logout();
```

**header.vue**

```
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';
import { inject } from 'vue';
import { Auth0 } from '@/auth';
export type TAuthPlugin = typeof Auth0;
export default defineComponent({
  name: 'HeaderMenu',
  inject: ['authPlugin'],
  methods: {
    login() {
      this.auth.loginWithRedirect();
    },
    logout() {
      // this.$AuthPlugin.logout();
      this.$router.push({ path: '/' });
    },
  },
  setup() {
    const auth = inject<TAuthPlugin>('Auth');
    // console.log(auth.loginWithRedirect);
    // /* eslint-disable */

    return {
      auth,
    };
  },
});
</script>
```

**The auth index.ts for reference.**

```
import createAuth0Client, {
  Auth0Client,
  GetIdTokenClaimsOptions,
  GetTokenSilentlyOptions,
  GetTokenWithPopupOptions,
  LogoutOptions,
  RedirectLoginOptions,
  User,
} from '@auth0/auth0-spa-js';
import { App, Plugin, computed, reactive, watchEffect } from 'vue';
import { NavigationGuardWithThis } from 'vue-router';

let client: Auth0Client;

interface Auth0PluginState {
  loading: boolean;
  isAuthenticated: boolean;
  user: User | undefined;
  popupOpen: boolean;
  error: any;
}

const state = reactive<Auth0PluginState>({
  loading: true,
  isAuthenticated: false,
  user: {},
  popupOpen: false,
  error: null,
});

async function handleRedirectCallback() {
  state.loading = true;

  try {
    await client.handleRedirectCallback();
    state.user = await client.getUser();
    state.isAuthenticated = true;
  } catch (e) {
    state.error = e;
  } finally {
    state.loading = false;
  }
}

function loginWithRedirect(o: RedirectLoginOptions) {
  return client.loginWithRedirect(o);
}

function getIdTokenClaims(o: GetIdTokenClaimsOptions) {
  return client.getIdTokenClaims(o);
}

function getTokenSilently(o: GetTokenSilentlyOptions) {
  return client.getTokenSilently(o);
}

function getTokenWithPopup(o: GetTokenWithPopupOptions) {
  return client.getTokenWithPopup(o);
}

function logout(o: LogoutOptions) {
  return client.logout(o);
}

const authPlugin = {
  isAuthenticated: computed(() => state.isAuthenticated),
  loading: computed(() => state.loading),
  user: computed(() => state.user),
  getIdTokenClaims,
  getTokenSilently,
  getTokenWithPopup,
  handleRedirectCallback,
  loginWithRedirect,
  logout,
};

const routeGuard: NavigationGuardWithThis<undefined> = (to: any, from: any, next: any) => {
  const { isAuthenticated, loading, loginWithRedirect } = authPlugin;

  const verify = async () => {
    // If the user is authenticated, continue with the route
    if (isAuthenticated.value) {
      return next();
    }

    // Otherwise, log in
    await loginWithRedirect({ appState: { targetUrl: to.fullPath } });
  };

  // If loading has already finished, check our auth state using `fn()`
  if (!loading.value) {
    return verify();
  }

  // Watch for the loading property to change before we check isAuthenticated
  watchEffect(() => {
    if (!loading.value) {
      return verify();
    }
  });
};

interface Auth0PluginOptions {
  domain: string;
  clientId: string;
  audience: string;
  redirectUri: string;

  onRedirectCallback(appState: any): void;
}

async function init(options: Auth0PluginOptions): Promise<Plugin> {
  client = await createAuth0Client({
    // domain: process.env.VUE_APP_AUTH0_DOMAIN,
    // client_id: process.env.VUE_APP_AUTH0_CLIENT_KEY,
    domain: options.domain,
    client_id: options.clientId,
    audience: options.audience,
    redirect_uri: options.redirectUri,
  });

  try {
    // If the user is returning to the app after authentication
    if (window.location.search.includes('code=') && window.location.search.includes('state=')) {
      // handle the redirect and retrieve tokens
      const { appState } = await client.handleRedirectCallback();

      // Notify subscribers that the redirect callback has happened, passing the appState
      // (useful for retrieving any pre-authentication state)
      options.onRedirectCallback(appState);
    }
  } catch (e) {
    state.error = e;
  } finally {
    // Initialize our internal authentication state
    state.isAuthenticated = await client.isAuthenticated();
    state.user = await client.getUser();
    state.loading = false;
  }

  // return {
  //   install: (app: App<Element>) => {
  //     app.provide('Auth', authPlugin);
  //   },

  return {
    install: (app: App) => {
      app.provide('Auth', authPlugin);
    },
  };
}

interface Auth0Plugin {
  init(options: Auth0PluginOptions): Promise<Plugin>;
  routeGuard: NavigationGuardWithThis<undefined>;
}

export const Auth0: Auth0Plugin = {
  init,
  routeGuard,
};
```

​[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cF9C.png): [Vue 3 with Typescript inject does not work as intended. Spread types may only be created from object types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70277408/vue-3-with-typescript-inject-does-not-work-as-intended-spread-types-may-only-b)

Comment: I didn't follow what happens with auth0 api here,, but how `authPlugin` and `Auth0` are related? They are clearly different objects. If you expect `authPlugin` to be injected, don't type it with `typeof Auth0`. Notice that the answer to previous question says that you need `typeof authPlugin`

Comment: Auth0 and authPlugin should be the same object, or at least that was the intention. I just want to access methods from Auth0 in my component

Comment: Looks like I don't need provide in the main.ts as I get an instance from auth which I can see is... ``` return {
    install: (app: App) => {
      app.provide('Auth', authPlugin);
    },
  };```

Comment: I'm not sure about the intention, because they obviously aren't the same. See `const authPlugin` and `const Auth0` declarations in your code. "Looks like I don't need provide in the main.ts" - yes, you don't need it, it you wanted to import it directly instead of using a plugin, you could do that without using provide/inject

Comment: So, `AuthPlugin` init() in my main.ts and I have `.use(AuthPlugin)` if I want access to the object in my view directly I don't need 'inject" ? maybe something like `this.$AuthPlugin`

Comment: Thank you for the responce. I can now see I have access to `this.$.appContext.provides.Auth` which looks like what I need, is this what you mean?

Comment: I mean that provide/inject is suitable for specific goals, like loose coupling, or deep DI. It's used in third-party plugins for this reason, but in your own app you may not need a plugin at all. Just import `authPlugin` (or whatever you call it) from auth module wherever you use it. `this.$AuthPlugin` - this is an obsolete way to handle global dependencies, primarily caused by the lack of modules, which is not the case in modern TS environment

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `authPlugin` and `Auth0` are unrelated objects.

It should be either `provide('authPlugin', authPlugin)` and `inject<typeof authPlugin>('authPlugin')`, or `provide('authPlugin', Auth0)` and `inject<typeof Auth0>('authPlugin')`.

In this case `inject` is not even needed. It's commonly used for loose coupling in third-party plugins, can also be used for deep dependency injection in nested components. Unless it's required by application design for auth to be a separate package, it doesn't need to be a plugin and `provide`/`inject`. Since `authPlugin`  is defined when a module is evaluated, it can be just exported from `auth` module and imported where it's used.